# Docker using 100% CPU

Tags: node.js, docker, ghost-blog, ghost

As you can see from the graphs below, I am having an interesting issue. I have a 2GB VPS running three Ghost (blogging platform that runs on node) containers. Node's memory usage creeps up and up until about 95% where it does a massive garbage collection. This causes a huge spike on the Disk I/O and CPU kits 100% and then... stays there.

Any ideas what could be going on here? I've been looking around for days and I can't find any helpful information. My web server is still responsive, websites load etc.

[image]

Comment: What is the output of `docker stats` are you able to SSH to the machine?

Comment: I can SSH into the server, `docker stats` comes up blank :\

Comment: what docker version are you using? This indicates that daemon itself is busy instead of the containers. I would suggest you run `journalctl` and see if you can find a issue near the timestamp

Comment: I am using the latest stable docker release for CentOS EL 7.

Comment: I can't really see anything terribly peculiar in journalctl. I see several  instances where docker runs a kill command when it reaches out of memory state (because node is stupid).

Comment: I would suggest you run your node containers with a memory limit specified and see if that helps?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163533/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-karai17).

Comment: It could be that your server is swapping. Try running `top` in your server and see what process is actually eating CPU

Comment: What is shown in `docker events`

Comment: `dockerd` is using 99% CPU. `docker events` shows nothing at all.